# Как написать код java на андроид чтобы в приложении ввести номер телефона и сумму, затем вывести её на киви кошелёк?

Tags: java

Я создал приложение для заработка на sketchware, но не знаю как из приложения вывести деньги на киви кошелёк. Мне нужно вводить свой номер телефона и сумму затем когда нажимаю на кнопку (вывод на киви) чтобы через несколько минут пришли деньги.
Как написать код java на андроид?

Answer (score 0):

Вам надо смотреть есть ли такое API у Qiwi. Если есть - смотрите его документацию, отправляйте нужные запросы/открывайте нужные страницы в браузере и выводите. Но такого API может не быть или требуется много бумажной волокиты для получения доступа к нему.

В крайнем случае вы всегда можете направить юзера на сайт Qiwi чтобы юзер всё там самостоятельно сделал, без вашего участия.